# Multiple tensorflow-gpu Versions with Conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using Windows 10 with the latest pip and Conda versions.
I am trying to set up two different Conda environments with different versions of `tensorflow-gpu`, CUDA and cuDNN. But I am not sure if it's even possible. Any reply is greatly appreciated.

I am currently perfectly running a `tf-gpu=2.1` with `python=3.7`, `cuda=10.1` and `cudnn=7.6.5`. But I would like to create a new environment of `tf-gpu=1.13.1` with `python=3.6`, `cuda=10.0` and `cudnn=7.4.2`. I am having trouble with it, and wondering if it's doable. For the second environment, the Cuda and cuDNN versions are matched from a post I have seen a few days ago. Thank you.

p.s. if you're wondering, the second environment is for [stable-baselines](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines) which is only compatible with `1.8.0 < tf < 1.14.0`.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to do that, normally virtual environments are handled (if you are doing it this way there is no problem) each environment will work differently as you configure it.either way you can check the information in the official documentation in https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html